# Наводило и Бездолье

Tags: словообразование

Интересно, от чего образованы эти слова?

Comment: Если разобрать по составу эти слова, получится выделить корни?  Потом попробуйте поискать однокоренные.

Answer (score 2):

Это наводило тоску. Наводило - н.ф. на/вод/и/ть-от на/вес/ти (черед.е/о,с/д)-суффиксальный.Несов. вид часто образовывается от сов.
на+водить -не оправдывается, это же не водить по направлению куда-то, а ведя, направить, значит, от инф. вести, а не водить(многократное действие)

Бездолье-(без) доли + суфф.j - прист.-суфф.